# python hangman (another one)

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, hangman

I'm pretty new to python and have created a simple hangman. Since doing so I realise this appears to be a fairy common theme.
It uses /usr/share/dict/words on the local system, resulting in some tricky words to guess. I guess I should look at maybe curl'ing a URL to get random words or an API. I've also not defined a main(), not sure if that's bad practice. Feedback appreciated.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import os
import random
import subprocess

def draw_man_and_show_word():
   global word
   showword=''.join(word)
   os.system('clear')
   for y in range(0,7):
      for x in range(0,7):
         print (chr(array[y][x]),end='')
      print()
   print () 
   print (showword)
   print () 

def add_limb_to_man():
   global size
   y=man[size][0]
   x=man[size][1]
   c=man[size][2]
   array[x][y]=c 
   size=size+1

def find_random_word():
   global theword
   lines=int(subprocess.getoutput("wc -l /usr/share/dict/words | awk \'{print $1}\'"))
   line=random.randint(1,lines)
   theword=subprocess.getoutput("head -"+str(line)+" /usr/share/dict/words |tail -1")
   theword=str.lower(theword) 

# 2D array of character (ASCII) values as a matrix for the hangman pic
array=[[124,45,45,45,45,32,32,32],[124,32,32,32,124,32,32,32],[124,32,32,32,32,32,32,32],[124,32,32,32,32,32,32,32],[124,32,32,32,32,32,32,32],[124,32,32,32,32,32,32,32],[124,32,32,32,32,32,32,32]]

# 2D array with the (single) character position to change (x,y,newvalue) for each additional limb
man=[[4,2,79],[4,3,43],[3,3,47],[5,3,92],[4,4,124],[3,5,47],[5,5,92]]

size=tries=0
limit=6
letters_tried=""

find_random_word()

# Array to represent word shown on screen (using array as string immutable)
word=['-' for x in range(0,len(theword))]

while ((tries <= limit)):
   draw_man_and_show_word()

   letter=""
   while (len(letter) != 1 or not letter.islower() or letters_tried.find(letter) >= 0):
      letter=input("Enter your choice of (single lowercase) letter:")

   letters_tried=letters_tried+letter

   pos=theword.find(letter)
   if (pos >= 0):
      tmpword=theword
      while (pos >= 0):
         word[pos]=letter
         tmpword=tmpword.replace(letter,'#',1)
         pos=tmpword.find(letter)

   else:
      add_limb_to_man()
      tries=tries+1

   if (''.join(word) == theword):
      draw_man_and_show_word()
      print()
      print("you got it!")
      exit()

draw_man_and_show_word()

print ("you lost. It was "+theword)
```

Comment: Edit: corrected the handling of counting lines in /usr/share/dict/words to allow it to not be mac specific, (slightly different wc output to fedora)  and added correct handling of letters already tried using letters_tried variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Avoid working in the global namespace

   This makes maintenance of code a pain. Instead create a `main` or `hangman` function
2. Don't use `global` instead make these variables parameters of you function

   > ```
   > def draw_man_and_show_word():
   >    global word
   > ```

   Could be

   ```
   def draw_man_and_show_word(word):
   ```
3. Don't make lines to long, they become really hard to read

   > ```
   > array=[[124,45,45,45,45,32,32,32],[124,32,32,32,124,32,32,32],[124,32,32,32,32,32,32,32],[124,32,32,32,32,32,32,32],[124,32,32,32,32,32,32,32],[124,32,32,32,32,32,32,32],[124,32,32,32,32,32,32,32]]
   > ```

   See how you need to scroll all the way to the right, this would be much more easy on the eyes

   ```
   HANGMAN =  [
                  ['|', '-', '-', '-', '-', ' ', ' ', ' '],
                  ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' '],
                  ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
                  ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
                  ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
                  ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
                  ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
              ]
   ```

   I also changed it to their character form which makes it even more easy to read

   And made the variable name `ALL_CAPS` since this is a constant
4. Use unpacking // *Optional namedtuple*

   > ```
   > man=[[4,2,79],[4,3,43],[3,3,47],[5,3,92],[4,4,124],[3,5,47],[5,5,92]]
   > y=man[size][0]
   > x=man[size][1]
   > c=man[size][2]
   > array[x][y]=c 
   > size=size+1
   > ```

   First I cleaned it up a bit

   ```
   HANGMAN_STAGES = [
                        [4, 2, 'O'],
                        [4, 3, '+'],
                        [3, 3, '/'],
                        [5, 3, '\\'],
                        [4, 4, '|'],
                        [3, 5, '/'],
                        [5, 5, '\\']
                    ]
   ```

   And we can unpack the values from the list of lists with this

   `x, y, value = HANGMAN_STAGES[size]`

   Alternatively you can use the [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) module to store information more visually

   The it would become

   ```
   from collections import namedtuple

   Stage = namedtuple('Stage', 'x, y, value')
   HANGMAN_STAGES = [
                        Stage(4, 2, 'O'),
                        Stage(4, 3, '+'),
                        Stage(3, 3, '/'),
                        Stage(5, 3, '\\'),
                        Stage(4, 4, '|'),
                        Stage(3, 5, '/'),
                        Stage(5, 5, '\\')
                    ]
   ```

   And you can call them like this

   ```
   stage = HANGMAN_STAGES[size]
   HANGMAN[stage.y][stage.x] = stage.value
   ```
5. Make the `guessed_letters` a `set()`

   For fast lookup O(0)
6. `join()` instead of manually appending chars

   > ```
   > for y in range(0,7):
   >     for x in range(0,7):
   >         print (chr(array[y][x]),end='')
   >     print()
   > ```

   Could be rewritten as `print('\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in draw_list))`

   If we have changed the HANGMAN to contain `chr` instead of the ordinal values
7. Instead of the `find` and `replace` methods you could have used `enumerate`

   > ```
   > pos=theword.find(letter)
   > if (pos >= 0):
   >     tmpword=theword
   >     while (pos >= 0):
   >         word[pos]=letter
   >         tmpword=tmpword.replace(letter,'#',1)
   >         pos=tmpword.find(letter)
   > ```

   Can be rewritten in the form of

   ```
   for idx, char in enumerate(theword):
       if char == letter:
           guessed_word[idx] = letter
   ```

   But `strings` can't be assigned... so you should set the data type of guessed_word to a `list`
8. Lastly top it off with a `if __name__ == '__main__'`

## Putting it all together

```
import random

HANGMAN =  [
                ['|', '-', '-', '-', '-', ' ', ' ', ' '],
                ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|', ' ', ' ', ' '],
                ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
                ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
                ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
                ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
                ['|', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
           ]

HANGMAN_STAGES = [
                    [4, 2, 'O'],
                    [4, 3, '+'],
                    [3, 3, '/'],
                    [5, 3, '\\'],
                    [4, 4, '|'],
                    [3, 5, '/'],
                    [5, 5, '\\']
                 ]
SPACE = '_'

def print_man_and_word(draw_list, guessed_word):
    print('\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in draw_list))
    print()
    print(''.join(guessed_word))

def get_random_word():
    # Your logic here (I don't have linux atm ;)
    word_list = ['cheese', 'pepper', 'sausage']
    return random.choice(word_list)

def get_letter(guessed_letters):
    letter = ''
    while len(letter) != 1 or not letter.islower() or letter in guessed_letters:
        letter = input("Enter your choice of (single lowercase) letter:")
    return letter

def hangman(word=None, draw_list=HANGMAN):
    if word is None:
        word = get_random_word()

    guessed_word = [SPACE] * len(word)
    guessed_letters = set()
    tries = 0

    while True:
        print_man_and_word(draw_list, guessed_word)
        letter = get_letter(guessed_letters)
        guessed_letters.add(letter)

        if letter in word:
            for idx, char in enumerate(word):
                if char == letter:
                    guessed_word[idx] = letter
        else:
            x, y, value = HANGMAN_STAGES[tries]
            draw_list[y][x] = value
            tries += 1

        if all(char != SPACE for char in guessed_word):
            print_man_and_word(draw_list, guessed_word)
            print('\nYou got it!')
            exit()

        elif tries == len(HANGMAN_STAGES):
            print_man_and_word(draw_list, guessed_word)
            print('You lost! it is {}'.format(word))
            exit()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hangman()
```